# How to save multiple items in array to database in NodeJS/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So first of all im getting a post via a form that returns to me multiple lines of text

then i use the following to split it into multiple urls

```
var str = req.body.url;
var split = str.split('\n');
```

then i get this

```
[urlone,urltwo,urlthree]
```

my save function works fine for one document
i just cant seem to submit all three at the same time to mongo via mongoose commands .

ive tried a few forEach loops . and got no help

I can really use some help here 
I'm really new to nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Define Model:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

let ModelSchema = new Schema(
  {
    property: String,

    urls: []
  },
  {    
    collection: 'models',
    strict: true,
    autoIndex: true
  }
);

module.exports = Model = mongoose.model('Model', ModelSchema);
```

Now, you can create or update any record.

```
let urlArray = req.body.url.split('\n');
```

// solution 1

```
let myModel = new Model();
myModel.property = 'xxx';
myModel.urls = urlArray;
myModel.save();
```

// solution 2

```
Model.update({ property: 'xxxx' }, { $set: { urls: urlArray } }, { upsert: true }, function(err, res) {
  // continue to check err/res
})
```

// solution 3, prevent from duplicate entries

```
Model.update({ property: 'xxxx' }, { $addToSet: { urls: urlArray } }, { upsert: true }, function(err, res) {
  // continue to check err/res
})
```